Import npm package from extraResources JS file in Electron fails
In my extraResources directory, I have a batch.js file that imports npm packages.
I exec() a child process in the main electron process to run the batch.js file. The command looks like this: exec('node ${process.extraResources}/extra_resources/batch.js').
The batch.js file runs seamlessly in the Development mode, but when I build the app, batch.js file fails to load the npm packages.
I used electron-vite, which uses electron-builder, to initialize my Electron project.
My project structure:
src/extra_resources/batch.js
src/main/...
src/preload/...
src/renderer

My electron-builder.yml
appId: com.electron.app
productName: automation-electron
directories:
  buildResources: build
files:
  - '!**/.vscode/*'
  - '!src/*'
  - '!electron.vite.config.{js,ts,mjs,cjs}'
  - '!{.eslintignore,.eslintrc.cjs,.prettierignore,.prettierrc.yaml,dev-app-update.yml,CHANGELOG.md,README.md}'
  - '!{.env,.env.*,.npmrc,pnpm-lock.yaml}'
  - '!{tsconfig.json,tsconfig.node.json,tsconfig.web.json}'
asarUnpack:
  - resources/**
win:
  executableName: automation-electron
extraResources:
  from: './src/extra_resources/'
  to: extra_resources
  filter:
    - '**/*'
nsis:
  artifactName: ${name}-${version}-setup.${ext}
  shortcutName: ${productName}
  uninstallDisplayName: ${productName}
  createDesktopShortcut: always
mac:
  entitlementsInherit: build/entitlements.mac.plist
  extendInfo:
    - NSCameraUsageDescription: Application requests access to the device's camera.
    - NSMicrophoneUsageDescription: Application requests access to the device's microphone.
    - NSDocumentsFolderUsageDescription: Application requests access to the user's Documents folder.
    - NSDownloadsFolderUsageDescription: Application requests access to the user's Downloads folder.
  notarize: false
dmg:
  artifactName: ${name}-${version}.${ext}
linux:
  target:
    - AppImage
    - snap
    - deb
  maintainer: electronjs.org
  category: Utility
appImage:
  artifactName: ${name}-${version}.${ext}
npmRebuild: false
publish:
  provider: generic
  url: https://example.com/auto-updates

